# Considering sign when calculating work

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, conventions

How to calculate the work done by gravity when an object is falling from a height of 10 to 5?

I have come with the following two formulae:

$$W =\int_{10}^{5}-mg \space d(-h)$$

$$W =\int_{10}^{5}-mg \space d(h)$$

I believe that the former one is right because force of gravity and object both go down, but it seems proper says that the latter is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter is correct. While writing the equation you need not care about the sign of displacement in the first step. You only have to take care of the sign of the acting force. 
As you will integrate with respect to position you will have to substitute the initial and final positions of the object and therefore after substituting the limits you will automatically get the correct answer. 
The work done would be positive as both force and displacement are along the same line. 
If you use the former formula you will get negative result which will be wrong